# My first custom made cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I have create for first time a shopping cart from scratch for a very special project.

At this time I have complete all the steps, from product selection / customization, to shopping cart product quantity update and other stuff that required.

My whole shopping cart is stored in session variable, encrypted.

My problem now, is that I don't know what is the best way to proceed to check out via PayPal.

Now I building the cart review page. The question is, how to send the cart information to paypal ?

Is it good way to add hidden fields in review page inside a form and send that information in PayPal with post method ?

This method is not so good, because an end user with knowledge, has the ability to alter that data.

Any idea on how to continue ?

Comment: Paypal has more solutions than the simple post-form method; you can find them all at their developer channel: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-how-to-guides ; you are correct to assume the form is unsafe.

Comment: Side note: there's no need to encrypt session data. If you can't trust your sessions, you have bigger problems.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, There is not way an end user with high level of knowledge to modify the session data ? I am not 100% sure, and this is the reason I encrypt the session data.